# Where do these three dc error input voltage comes from?

Tags: operational-amplifier

The book said that there are three unwanted dc error input in an differential Amplifier:

[image]
[image]

Wherein:
$$I_{in(bias)} = \frac{I_{b1} +I_{b2}}{2}$$
$$I_{in(off)} =I_{b1} - I_{b2} $$
*(V_in(off) is input offset voltage)*

I don't understand what each error voltage refers to. For example:

- Why would V_1err becomes automatically zero when resistance is the same **regardless if current I_b1 and I_b2 is the same or not?**
- Why would V_2err becomes zero when current is the same **regardless if resistance Rb1 and Rb2 is same or not?**
- What is the difference of V_3err from the two error voltage above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume in the following circuit that \$V_-\$ and \$V_+\$ are at the exact same voltage, so that the differential is exactly zero volts:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0yhNQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then it follows that the collector currents are identical.

But it does not follow that the base currents are exactly the same, since the BJTs are different BJTs and they also may be at different temperatures, too. So, while we can for these purposes assume \$I_{\text{C}_1}=I_{\text{C}_2}\$, we must accept that \$I_{\text{B}_1}\ne I_{\text{B}_2}\$ since we have to assume that \$\beta_1\ne \beta_2\$.

There's another effect here. Even assuming that \$I_{\text{C}_1}=I_{\text{C}_2}\$ and recognizing that \$I_{\text{B}_1}\ne I_{\text{B}_2}\$, it's also likely that \$V_{\text{BE}_1}\ne V_{\text{BE}_2}\$. This is because the saturation currents of the two BJTs may also be different. So, while \$I_{\text{C}_1}=I_{\text{C}_2}\$ (our starting assumption that is required in order to ensure that \$V_-=V_+\$), we may have both \$I_{\text{B}_1}\ne I_{\text{B}_2}\$ and also \$V_{\text{BE}_1}\ne V_{\text{BE}_2}\$. Now, from the circuit we know absolutely that \$V_{\text{E}_1}= V_{\text{E}_2}\$, so the implication is that \$V_{\text{B}_1}\ne V_{\text{B}_2}\$.

If you are still following along, then I think you can see that:

$$\begin{align*}
V_1&=V_{\text{B}_1}+I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_1\\\\
V_2&=V_{\text{B}_2}+I_{\text{B}_2}\cdot R_2
\end{align*}$$

Please keep in mind here that the above equations are set up with the assumption that we've made all necessary adjustments to ensure that \$I_{\text{C}_1}=I_{\text{C}_2}\$ so that also \$V_-=V_+\$!

All we need to do now is to compute the difference between them:

$$\begin{align*}
V_1-V_2 &= V_{\text{B}_1}+I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_1 - \left(V_{\text{B}_2}+I_{\text{B}_2}\cdot R_2\right)\\\\
&=\left(V_{\text{B}_1} - V_{\text{B}_2}\right) + I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_{\text{B}_1}-I_{\text{B}_2}\cdot R_{\text{B}_2}\\\\
&=\left(V_{\text{B}_1} - V_{\text{B}_2}\right) + \frac12\,I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_{\text{B}_1} + \frac12\,I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_{\text{B}_1} - \frac12\,I_{\text{B}_2}\cdot R_{\text{B}_2} - \frac12\,I_{\text{B}_2}\cdot R_{\text{B}_2}\\&\hphantom{=\text{ } \left(V_{\text{B}_1} - V_{\text{B}_2}\right)}+\frac12\,I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_{\text{B}_2}- \frac12\,I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_{\text{B}_2} + \frac12\,I_{\text{B}_2}\cdot R_{\text{B}_1}  - \frac12\,I_{\text{B}_2}\cdot R_{\text{B}_1}\\\\
&=\left(V_{\text{B}_1} - V_{\text{B}_2}\right) + \frac12\,I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_{\text{B}_1}- \frac12\,I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_{\text{B}_2} + \frac12\,I_{\text{B}_2}\cdot R_{\text{B}_1} - \frac12\,I_{\text{B}_2}\cdot R_{\text{B}_2}\\&\hphantom{=\text{ } \left(V_{\text{B}_1} - V_{\text{B}_2}\right)}+ \frac12\,I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_{\text{B}_1} - \frac12\,I_{\text{B}_2}\cdot R_{\text{B}_1}+\frac12\,I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_{\text{B}_2}  - \frac12\,I_{\text{B}_2}\cdot R_{\text{B}_2}\\\\
&=\left(V_{\text{B}_1} - V_{\text{B}_2}\right)+\frac12\left(I_{\text{B}_1}+I_{\text{B}_2}\right)\left(R_{\text{B}_1}-R_{\text{B}_2}\right)+\frac12\left(I_{\text{B}_1}-I_{\text{B}_2}\right)\left(R_{\text{B}_1}+R_{\text{B}_2}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Now, you just break up those three parts:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{\text{ERR}_1}&=\left(R_{\text{B}_1}-R_{\text{B}_2}\right)\frac{I_{\text{B}_1}+I_{\text{B}_2}}{2}=\left(R_{\text{B}_1}-R_{\text{B}_2}\right) I_{\text{IN}_\text{BIAS}}\\\\
V_{\text{ERR}_2}&=\left(R_{\text{B}_1}+R_{\text{B}_2}\right)\frac{I_{\text{B}_1}-I_{\text{B}_2}}{2}=\left(R_{\text{B}_1}-R_{\text{B}_2}\right) I_{\text{IN}_\text{OFF}}\\\\
V_{\text{ERR}_3}&=V_{\text{B}_1} - V_{\text{B}_2} = V_{\text{IN}_\text{OFF}}\\\\
V_1-V_2 &= V_{\text{ERR}_1} + V_{\text{ERR}_2} + V_{\text{ERR}_3}
\end{align*}$$

And, of course, \$V_1-V_2\$ has \$A_v\$ applied to it at the output differential.

Answer (score 0):

The examples are correct but labels are inconsistent with most datasheets.

It's just an application of Ohm's Law or KVL on input currents and voltage.

[image]

1. When the Req for each input is not matched
2. This is difference in Input bias current which tends to be 10% of  1)
3. This is basic input offset voltage due to Vbe's

Comment: My question is more like:how this input error is generated. For example, *V_1err will become zero when resistance is same even if the current is different*, This feels wrong to me because even if resistance is the same, the voltage drop at each resistance is different(because of different current), and this difference in voltage drop will still produce error

Comment: Inpout Current differences are due to hFE differences with shared emitter current.

Comment: @IwataniNaofumi It's really, really simple math. They make it look complicated, is all.